# Error while running angular application error TS2305?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi I am running an angular application using the command ng serve. I can see the error like as follows.

```
 ERROR in src/app/accounts/account-form/account-form.component.ts(29,3): error TS2305: Module '"/home/prasanth/primecastworkspace3/primecast-web/src/app/shared/services/index"' has no exported member 'ModeService'.
```

my account-form.component.ts is as follows
account-form.component.ts

```
    import {
      AuthenticationService,
      FeaturesService,
      AddressProfilesService,
      FlightsService,
      MarketPropositionService
    } from '../../shared/services';
    @Component({
      selector: 'pc-account-form',
      templateUrl: './account-form.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./account-form.component.scss']
    })
    export class AccountFormComponent implements OnInit {

    }

index.ts file is as follows
export * from './accounts.service';
export * from './address-profiles.service';
export * from './authentication.service';
export * from './campaigns.service';
export * from './config.service';
export * from './confirm.service';
export * from './contact-lists.service';
export * from './countries.service';
export * from './features.service';
export * from './files.service';
export * from './flights.service';
export * from './forgot-password.service';
export * from './locations.service';
export * from './not-found.service';
export * from './languages.service';
export * from './locations.service';
export * from './notifications.service';
export * from './profile-parameters.service';
export * from './profiles.service';
export * from './recipient-gatherings.service';
export * from './settings.service';
export * from './templates.service';
export * from './toast.service';
export * from './users.service';
export * from './market-proposition.service';
```

market-proposition.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppConfig } from '../models';
import { MarketProposition } from '../models';
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class MarketPropositionService {
  config: AppConfig = this.configService.config;

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private configService: ConfigService
  ) {}

  get() {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<MarketProposition>(`${this.config.api}/find-market-proposition`)
      .pipe(shareReplay(1));
  }
}
```

All I am trying to do is inject a market proposition service object into my account-form.component.ts.

Earlier I was declaring the class ModeService class in a different file , but after refactoring it is throwing error.
please help

Comment: what version of angular are you running?

Comment: @GlobeAdmin if you want to inject the service remember to add it to the constructor of your component like so `constructor(marketPropositionService: MarketPropositionService)` , regarding the error I'm not sure though

Comment: @chris already constructor is present AccountFormComponent class with market proposition service injected

Comment: @cobolstinks angular 5 thank you – Globe Admin 46 mins ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually its my mistake . I changed in the angular code in vss code however i didnt save in the vss code. when i compared the file system using cat command and that with the gui i realised the issue